# How to allow the owner of a contract to set a deadline in days (and not have it inserted as seconds) in the constructor?

Tags: solidity, timestamp

thanks for taking the time to read this.

I'm having a bit of trouble handling time in Solidity. I want the owner of a contract to be able to set a deadline in days (which will be used in the rest of the contract) on the constructor. I wrote this:

```
constructor(uint _price, uint _days) public {
    owner = msg.sender;       
    price = _price;
    deadlineInDays = now + _days;
}
```

But as you may be aware, when the owner inputs any value in _days, it is added to the Epoch Time format (now). So, for example, if I set it to "10", when I call this function to return it:

```
function getPriceAndDeadline() public view returns (uint _price, uint _deadline) 
{
    return (price, deadlineInDays);
}
```

It returns something like this:

```
_price 1000
_deadline 1544005222 // this is only ten seconds after I ran the constructor
```

I obviously wanted it to return whatever "now" is plus "_days" in days, not in seconds.

I tried this (below), but it doesn't work.

```
constructor(uint _price, uint _days) public {
    owner = msg.sender;       
    price = _price;
    deadlineInDays = now + _days days;
}
```

Any ideas on how to handle this?

I appreciate any inputs in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
deadlineInDays = now + _days * 1 days;
```

It will be working.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, it worked like a breeze! Such a concise and elegant solution!